setup for engine development
I have retrieved texlive-source from GitHub, and I made some patches to the main engines (pdftex, xetex, luatex, euptex...).
The new binaries are created in a dedicated folder.
I run the modified tool from the command line (macOS) and the environment reads
TEXMF=/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist
TEXMFCNF=/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/web2c

While I want to keep the tree clean from development version, I also have
TEXMFVAR=<custom>/TexmfVar
TEXMFSYSVAR=<custom>/TexmfSysVar

My problem is that kpathsea does not find the format and recreates it each time, which takes too much time. When running some .../pdftex foo, pdftex.fmt is properly created by mktexfmt in directory $TEXMFSYSVAR/web2c/ and foo is properly typeset into foo.pdf.
How to make kpathsea find the pdftex.fmt just created ?
